# How can I make a customizable circle segment length mixin?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to make an animated version of this picture:

[image]

To do so, I use a mixin for each of the circle segment. I can setup everything except for the circle segment length. In the picture, you can see that the center is a full circle, the orange one is like 80% and the next ones are around 40%.

Is it possible to update my mixin so that I can use a percent of the circle segment length as argument?

Here is what I have so far:

```html
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sc1"></div>
    <div id="sc2"></div>
    <div id="sc3"></div>
    <div id="sc4"></div>
    <div id="sc5"></div>
  </div>
```

```css
$width: 240px;
$height: 240px;

#container {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  position: relative;
}

@mixin semi-circle($w, $bg, $rt) {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(#{$width / 2} - #{$w / 2});
  border: $width/30 solid $bg;
  border-top: 0;
  width: $w;
  transform: rotate($rt);
  height: $w/2;
  border-bottom-left-radius: $w;
  border-bottom-right-radius: $w;
  animation: rotate 1200ms ease-in-out 3;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#sc1 {
  @include semi-circle($width/6, #ffdc00, 0deg);
}

#sc2 {
  @include semi-circle($width/(60/19), #fba421, 10deg);
  animation-delay: -200ms;
}

#sc3 {
  @include semi-circle($width/(15/7), #c43688, -20deg);
  animation-delay: -400ms;
}

#sc4 {
  @include semi-circle($width/(60/37), #793e79, 20deg);
  animation-delay: -600ms;
}

#sc5 {
  @include semi-circle($width/(30/23), #5c3190, 60deg);
  animation-delay: -700ms;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

And here is a codepen with the code running (can't use preprocessors with SO snippets):https://codepen.io/billybobbonnet/pen/QWddwKg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SVG. It was requiring too many tricks to achieve this with CSS alone.
https://codepen.io/billybobbonnet/pen/xxggOKd

```html
<svg id="page-loader">
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="20" />
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="39" />
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="58" />
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="77" />
    <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="96" />
</svg>
```

```css
/* Align items to the center -- just for presentation purposes. */
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* 1. Style the SVG circles. */
#page-loader {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

    #page-loader circle {
        stroke-width: 9;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        fill: none;
    }

        #page-loader circle:nth-child(1) {
            stroke: #ffdc00;
            stroke-dasharray: 160;
        }

        #page-loader circle:nth-child(2) {
            stroke: #fba421;
            stroke-dasharray: 180 50;
            stroke-dashoffset: 80;
        }

        #page-loader circle:nth-child(3) {
            stroke: #c43688;
            stroke-dasharray: 140 160;
            stroke-dashoffset:-120;
        }

        #page-loader circle:nth-child(4) {
            stroke: #793e79;
            stroke-dasharray: 180 500;
            stroke-dashoffset: -80;
        }

        #page-loader circle:nth-child(5) {
            stroke: #5c3190;
            stroke-dasharray: 200 500;
            stroke-dashoffset: -150;
        }

/* 2. Create the keyframe animation. We start at 50% so the circle will rotate back to its original position. */
@keyframes loader {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#page-loader circle {
    animation-name: loader;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

    #page-loader circle:nth-of-type(1) {
        animation-delay: -0.2s;
    }

    #page-loader circle:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation-delay: -0.4s;
    }

    #page-loader circle:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation-delay: -0.6s;
    }

    #page-loader circle:nth-of-type(4) {
        animation-delay: -0.8s;
    }
```